# Optimizing BigInt recursive function

Tags: c++

This is a recursive function that I wrote using maps, it works but the run time is extremely slow. How can I optimize this function?

```
BigInt bitcon(int n)
{
static map<BigInt, BigInt> fiboMap;
BigInt bigN(n);
if (bigN == 1) return BigInt(100);
if (bigN == 2) return BigInt(200);
if (bigN == 3) return BigInt(300);
map<BigInt, BigInt>::iterator it = fiboMap.find(bigN);
if (it != fiboMap.end())
    return it->second;
else
    return fiboMap[bigN] = (BigInt(n) * (bitcon(n-1) + bitcon(n-2) - bitcon(n-3)));
```

Comment: @MartinKristiansen it's static

Comment: Profile an optimised build.

Comment: @RichardCritten the time complexity is too high, after bitcon(5), the program takes far too long to compute values

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

struct BigInt {
    unsigned long long n;
    BigInt() : n(0) {}
    BigInt(long long _n) : n(_n) {}
    unsigned long long get() const { return n; }
    bool operator==(long long other) const { return n == other; }
    bool operator<(const BigInt &b) const { return get() < b.get(); }
    BigInt operator+(const BigInt other) const { return BigInt(n + other.get()); }
    BigInt operator-(const BigInt other) const { return BigInt(n - other.get()); }
    BigInt operator*(const BigInt other) const { return BigInt(n * other.get()); }
};

BigInt bitcon(int n)
{
static std::map<BigInt, BigInt> fiboMap;
BigInt bigN(n);
if (bigN == 1) return BigInt(100);
if (bigN == 2) return BigInt(200);
if (bigN == 3) return BigInt(300);
std::map<BigInt, BigInt>::iterator it = fiboMap.find(bigN);
if (it != fiboMap.end())
    return it->second;
else
    return fiboMap[bigN] = (BigInt(n) * (bitcon(n-1) + bitcon(n-2) - bitcon(n-3)));
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::cout <<i<<"->"<<bitcon(i).get()<<" ";
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout <<std::endl<<duration<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Runs in 117 microsecond on www.onlinegdb.com. Sadly, i needed to invent BigInt, cause you didn't provide one.
As for the question (please state the question in the question "header" next time) using static map is a good idea, if you calculate the same value multiple times. And if you don't care about memory footprint. Also using recursion is ok too, still, if your stack is pretty big. Map will slow you down, when you are calculating a new value, because all new (n-3) BigInt objects will need to be stored inside this map. However I would:

- don't use map, just use a vector, BitInt's in fiboMap are ordered. Anyway, if I would need to use a map, i would map ints to BigInts, as int is the function argument.
- don't compare bigN with 1, 2 and 3 (probably that calls BigInt constructor and/or operator==), why don't you just compare `n`? Also, you may use a switch statement, but a decent compiler should optimize anyway.
- use `assert(n > 0);`, i guess your function is not intended to run with `n <= 0`
- probably prefer BigInt::operator*(int) over BigInt::operator*(BigInt) , but that depends on BitInt implementation

But that's all and that's not much, this function is ok as it is. So, if the function is really slow, my guess there is something slow in the BigInt.

```
BigInt bitcon2(int n)
{
    assert(n > 0);
    switch(n) {
        case 1: return BigInt(100);
        case 2: return BigInt(200);
        case 3: return BigInt(300);
    }
    static std::vector<BigInt> cache;
    const int idx = n - 4;
    if (cache.size() > idx)
        return cache.at(idx);
    BigInt ret = (bitcon(n-1) + bitcon(n-2) - bitcon(n-3)) * n;
    cache.push_back(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

However the speedup (if any) is negligible.